# What is $\Bbb R^{\times}$? [unit group, ring to "times" power]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

I'm doing some sheets for my Abstract Algebra class and I can't seem to remember the group defined as $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$. It's obviously some variation of $\mathbb{R}$ but I'm away from college on reading week so can't ask my tutor. If someone could clear up the confusion I'd be grateful.

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ under multiplication, most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the usual notation for the *unit group* of the ring $R$, that is, the group of invertible elements using ring multiplication as the group operation. Note that this is usually not the same thing as $R \setminus \{0\}$, because most elements aren't invertible (if it is the same, your ring is a field, by definition). While you can talk about $R \setminus \{0\}$ under multiplication, it's usually just a monoid (or even a semigroup, if you permit rings without unity).

Comment: Every element except $0$ in a ring can be invertible and the ring still isn't field, it needn't be commutative.

Answer (score -1):

The notation is often used on the form $\Bbb R^*$ i.e. with a star and it means $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ and we have $(\Bbb R^*,\times)$ is a multiplicative  group.

Comment: This is only true if $R$ is a field.

Comment: However, $\mathbb{R}^*$ can be used for $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. Some people don't like $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ for that since for them, closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is just $\mathbb{R}$.