# Notation question, what is $\mathbb{Q}^\times$?

Tags: notation, rational-numbers

For context, I'm starting to learn group theory, and one question is "Is $(\mathbb{Q}^\times, \cdot)$ a group?" Not looking for help with the question, just wondering what $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ means.

If it was by itself, I would have assumed rationals with multiplication, but it just seems to be a set. My next guess is rationals without zero, is that correct?

Comment: Your book is asking a strange question. By $\mathbb{Q}^\times$, most mathematicians mean "the non-zero rational numbers, under multiplication," which is a group. But your book seems to think $0$ is a member of the set; otherwise it doesn't make sense for that to be the identity of the group.

Comment: Formatting tip:  try `\mathbb Q`

Comment: @hunter This is probably a typo: $(Q^{\times},0)$ is supposed to be $(\Bbb Q^{\times},\circ)$, where $a\circ b$ is multiplication. Handwritten $a\circ b$ looks like $a \, 0\,  b$.

Comment: `\mathbb` or `\Bbb`, not `\mathds`

Comment: Edits of typos have been made, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\Bbb R^{\times}$? \[unit group, ring to "times" power\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690301/what-is-bbb-r-times-unit-group-ring-to-times-power)

Comment: Wasn't expecting to have this zero-upvote question from 3 years ago ressurected for it to be marked as duplicate, StackExchange always finds a way though it seems. Yes, these are similar, mine's Q rather than R though, mathematically identical but this a notation question, and I'm guessing that's why the other one didn't show up with the automatic duplicate checker. Feel free to mark as duplicate if you're trying to clean things up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a commutative ring $R$ often the *group of units* is denoted by $R^{\times}$, or also by $U(R)$. In the case when $R$ is a field, it coincides with $R\setminus 0$.

For example, $\Bbb Z[i]^{\times}=\{1,-1,i,-i \}$ and $\Bbb Q(i)^{\times}=\Bbb Q(i)\setminus 0$. Or $\Bbb Z^{\times}=\{1,-1\}$ and
$\Bbb Q^{\times}=\Bbb Q\setminus 0$.

Comment: In the general case, $R\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace$ is written as $A^\ast$. Therefore, $A$ is a field if and only if $A^\times=A^\ast$ (this is rewriting the definition). Also in the general case, $(A^\times,\times)$ is always a group, when considering the ring multiplication as the group law.

Comment: To avoid confusion I did not mention $R^*$, which is also used. But the question does not mention $R^*$. It is about a group, the group of units, or the multiplicative group of a field.

Comment: I still thought commenting about it would somehow be helpful, since both notations are pretty common and often misunderstood and even sometimes interchanged :)